# Prove the Triangle ABC is isoceles

Tags: geometry

If BD is a perpendicular bisector of AC , prove that ∆ABC isosceles.￼
[image]

Because BD is perpendicular to AC , m∠BDA = m∠BDC = 90°, but I am not sure how to continue. Thank you.

Comment: Hint: Consider some trigonometric formulas and the graph of tan $x$ from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: You could do this with a congruence argument or with the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: BD bisects AC , AD ≅ CD . Because BD ≅ BD (due to the reflexive property), ∆ADB ≅ ∆CDB
because of SAS. Would that also work?

Comment: Yep, that should do it.